# Truth table as the keys for a dictionary

Tags: c#, algorithm, dictionary

I have six boolean flags that are independent of each other so there are 64 possible combinations. These flags should determine the value of some string. This string can have seven different values. I think implementing this as a large if-statement is a bad idea so I thought of creating a truth table where each combination determines a specific outcome:

```
Key            Value
0,0,0,0,0,0 -> "A"
0,0,0,0,0,1 -> "A"
0,0,0,0,1,0 -> "B"
0,0,0,0,1,1 -> "C"
0,0,0,1,0,0 -> "A"
...
```

This looks remarkably like a dictionary but what would be the best key implementation (in C#)? The smallest possible key would be a `byte` that I mask the options into. However, this wouldn't improve the readability of my code.

Are there other solutions for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could represent the 6 bool options as an enum with the [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx), and rely on the readability of your enum names.

Edit, for example:

```
[Flags]
enum MyFlagSet : byte
{
    NoFlags = 0,
    Flag1 = 1 << 0,
    Flag2 = 1 << 1,
    Flag3 = 1 << 2,
    Flag4 = 1 << 3,
    Flag5 = 1 << 4,
    Flag6 = 1 << 5
};

Dictionary MyDictionary = new Dictionary<MyFlagSet, string>()
                          {
                              {MyFlagSet.NoFlags, "Q"},
                              {MyFlagSet.Flag1 | MyFlagSet.Flag2, "A"},
                              {MyFlagSet.Flag3 | MyFlagSet.Flag5 | MyFlagSet.Flag6, "B"}
                          };
```

Comment: Pfew, 64 meaningful names. I already find it difficult to come up with one. If I choose this option, I would still have a problem determining the correct key based on the values of each of the six flags. Unless I assign each flag an int from `1,2,4,8,16,32` and OR them together. This brings me very close to using `byte` or `int` as a key.

Comment: @Ronald Wildenberg - The powers-of-two-ORed-together option is exactly what the FlagsAttribute is intended to convey. So you would only need six named values rather than 64.

Comment: @Jeffrey - You're right, my mistake. You don't need to think up 64 names. Thanks.

Comment: If all 64 possibilities will have an associated string, you can also directly cast the enum to an int and simply store the strings in an array.  Even if not all 64 possibilities will have names, an array is a good option, with a sentinel value (say, null) indicating that the key isn't mapped.  Clear intent is generally more important than performance, but an array lookup is just as clean in my mind (and more concise) than a Dictionary implementation.

Comment: @Dan - Thanks, that's a useful suggestion. Since the keys are integers from 0 to 63, an array may be a better choice than a Dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question - and answered, but since ran across this while looking for a solution myself, here's my take on it.

```
public interface ITruthTable<in T1, in T2, in T3, in T4>
{
    bool GetValue(T1 obj1, T2 obj2, T3 obj3, T4 obj4);
}
public static class TruthTable
{
    private interface IMutableTable
    {
        void AddRow(bool v1, bool v2, bool v3, bool v4, bool result = false);
    }

    private sealed class Table<T1, T2, T3, T4>: ITruthTable<T1, T2, T3, T4>, IMutableTable
    {
        private readonly Func<T1, bool> _column1;
        private readonly Func<T2, bool> _column2;
        private readonly Func<T3, bool> _column3;
        private readonly Func<T4, bool> _column4;

        private readonly List<bool[]> _rows = new List<bool[]>();
        private readonly List<bool> _results = new List<bool>();

        private readonly bool _default;

        public Table(Func<T1, bool> column1, Func<T2, bool> column2, Func<T3, bool> column3, Func<T4, bool> column4, bool defaultValue)
        {
            _column1 = column1;
            _column2 = column2;
            _column3 = column3;
            _column4 = column4;

            _default = defaultValue;
        }

        #region IMutableTable<T1,T2,T3,T4> Members

        void IMutableTable.AddRow(bool v1, bool v2, bool v3, bool v4, bool result)
        {
            _rows.Add(new bool[4]);
            var row = _rows[_rows.Count - 1];
            row[0] = v1;
            row[1] = v2;
            row[2] = v3;
            row[3] = v4;

            _results.Add(result);
        }

        #endregion

        #region ITruthTable<T1,T2,T3,T4> Members

        public bool GetValue(T1 obj1, T2 obj2, T3 obj3, T4 obj4)
        {
            var v1 = _column1(obj1);
            var v2 = _column2(obj2);
            var v3 = _column3(obj3);
            var v4 = _column4(obj4);

            for (int i = 0; i < _rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var row = _rows[i];
                if ((row[0] == v1) && (row[1] == v2) && (row[2] == v3) && (row[3] == v4))
                    return _results[i];
            }

            return _default;
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public static ITruthTable<T1, T2, T3, T4> Create<T1, T2, T3, T4>(Func<T1, bool> column1, Func<T2, bool> column2, Func<T3, bool> column3, Func<T4, bool> column4, bool defaultValue = false)
    {
        return new Table<T1, T2, T3, T4>(column1, column2, column3, column4, defaultValue);
    }

    public static ITruthTable<T1, T2, T3, T4> Row<T1, T2, T3, T4>(this ITruthTable<T1, T2, T3, T4> table, bool v1, bool v2, bool v3, bool v4, bool result)
    {
        (table as IMutableTable).AddRow(v1, v2, v3, v4, result);
        return table;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testTable = TruthTable.Create<bool, bool, bool, bool>
            (b => b /*Column description*/ , b => b /* Column 2 */ , b => b, b => b, defaultValue: false)
        .Row(false,                          false,                  false,  false, false)
        .Row(false,                          true,                   false,  true,  true)
        .Row(true,                           true,                   true,   false, false)
        .Row(true,                           false,                  true,   true,  true);

        var result = testTable.GetValue(false, true, false, true);
    }
```

Simple explanation: The funcs provided accept values for each column and convert them to bools. A simple loop then finds the first correct match and returns it's result value or returns the default value specified. the last value in each .Row call is the result if the inputs match that row.

Of course, this solution is for 4 generic parameters but it is simple to write tables for more or less parameters than this. Also, the simple case above uses a bool to bool mapping for the value extractors but in real world apps it might need to accept some other type of object and convert it to a bool input value for that column.

It was type-safe enough and good enough my needs, hope it helps someone else, too.

Comment: timing is perfect.  I was trying to figure out how I was going to come up with a clean method of testing out 16 use cases of 4 boolean options each. +1

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way:

```
struct KeyThing
{
  public int a,b,c,d,e,f;
}
```

The preferred way would be using bitmasks.

Comment: Do you mean `public bool a,b,c,d,e,f`?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an enum with the [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=VS.100).aspx), which may make your code easier to read, but you will have to make up 64 names!

Comment: The FlagsAttribute approach only requires 6 names (or 7, if you want to include no flags set, 0).

Answer (score 0):

Use a bitmask to create a int and store your values in a regular hash?

ie:
0,0,0,0,0,0 = 0
0,0,0,0,0,1 = 1
0,0,0,0,1,0 = 2

and then hash[0] = "a" and so on

Answer (score 0):

If you encapuslate the six-booleans-to-string function into a separate class, then the readability of the code becomes trivially improved regardless of the implementation details. And the implementation can change based on performance needs that arise.

(I am going to make up a name to illustrate.)

```
public static class RobotEmotionDescriptions
{
    public static string GetDescription(bool isHurting, bool isAwake, 
           bool isBrightlyLit, bool isInQuitePlace, bool isPlayingChess, 
           bool isTumpedOver)
    {
        ... // Details don’t matter.
    }
}
```

So I think the bitmapped byte would be an excellent first-pass to an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could represent your bool options as strings, e.g.
“011011”
then just use a Dictionary

(this may be a good option if you wish to let the user change the mappings, as reading strings from a file is easy)

However if you will be using them much, use a flags enum as per Luke’s answer.